# ajax jquery form not sending data on change

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I'm creating form for each item in cart/order i.e multiple forms in loop and giving them unique ids ('id'=>'cart_'.$line )(cart_1,cart_2). and created an update link in loop for each form. code below

```
 echo form_open($controller_name."/edit_item/$line", array('class'=>'form-horizontal line-item', 'id'=>'cart_'.$line));
echo form_input(array('name'=>'quantity','value'=>$item['quantity'],'size'=>'2', 'id'=>'quantity','class'=>'form-control cartline', 'data-form' => $line));
echo form_input(array('name'=>'discount','value'=>$item['discount'],'size'=>'3',  'id'=>'discount', 'class'=>'form-control cartline', 'data-form' => $line));?>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('<?php echo 'cart_'.$line ?>').submit();" id="anchor" title=<?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_update')?>  >
```

I want my form to submit via ajax  on onChange of quantity,discount field.
im trying but form not sending onChange

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".line-item").submit(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var line_form = $( this ),
        url = line_form.attr( 'action' );
        $.post(url,
        {
          quantity:$('quantity').val(),
          discount: $('discount').val()
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `I want my form to submit on onChange event of quantity field.` where is this event in your code? https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: how can i implement in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the event **change**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Here the element you want to trigger in change to send the form (quantity, disccount,...)
   $(".quantity").change(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var line_form = $( this ),
        url = line_form.attr( 'action' );
        $.post(url,
        {
          quantity:$('quantity').val(),
          discount: $('discount').val()
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Actually if you have few elements which could trigger the form submit you could do this:

```
<script>

    function submitForm(){
        //Here send by AJAX the form and handle all actions 
    }

    $('.elementTriggerSubmit').change(submitForm);
    $('#otherElement').change(submitForm);
</script>
```